# Spark is running before filter twice

Tags: java, spark-java

I'm mapping a filter to check some required fields before login. My code looks like:

```
before("/login", (req, res) -> {
    // do some things
    LOGGER.debug("before /login");
    LOGGER.debug("Request -> " + req);
    LOGGER.degub("body " + req.body());
}
```

When my app is running, the `before` filter is called twice.

In each one the `req` are different instances. In the first one the content of `req.body()` is an empty string. In the second one, the content is exactly what I sent from my client application.

Debugging, I've found a filter with path is described as `+/*paths` declared in [`SparkUtils`](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/blob/4a6a3888d89c0070268d827d060f660209bdc07b/src/main/java/spark/utils/SparkUtils.java) class.

There are two questions:

1. How can I disable that behavior?
2. What is the purpose of filter declared as `+/*paths`?

I believe that reason of filter being called twice, is because I've followed the steps to **Enabled CORS** as described [here](https://sparktutorials.github.io/2016/05/01/cors.html). Anyway, I need to use CORS, but the filter being called twice is been a problem in my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to use a filter. A filter is used when you need to check something, in different cases..

In your case, you need to check the body when it is the POST request (for example, I don't know what is your case exactly)

That filter, as you mentioned, is being called twice because of the OPTIONS and the POST request.

What you should do is move the validation to the method where you receive the request. For example something like:

```
Spark.post("/login", (req, res) -> {
    // validate..
    // do action..
});
```

Another option, if you really need to keep the filter, is to check the Request Method in the filter, and apply the validation to just the POST one, and not the OPTIONS one.

Comment: I did as you suggest, checking for using `if (HttpMethod.post.name().equalsIgnoreCase(req.requestMethod()))`. I'm not sure if it is elegant but it solves.

Comment: @josivan yes, it will work, but if you ask me, I personally think it is not elegant